# How do I get the missing stickers?

Tags: super-mario-3d-world

I used the game completion menu in game to go back and fetch all stickers in each level. However, I'm missing 9 stickers. A Starman, a golden lucky cat, an 8 bit mario/luigi, and what look like circles with silhouettes of the characters in them.

How do I get these extra stickers? I've beaten all levels in the game, including world 12 (flower), and have opened all the toad/sticker houses. I have most, but not all, gold flags and stars.

Comment: I am guessing that the stars and gold flags may have something to do with the missing stickers.

Comment: @Brian I unlocked yet another last world, world 12, and I have gotten two of the stickers, but I stikk can't account for all of them

Comment: Hmm... I am really not sure then.  Of course, I would like to know as well since I am at about the same point that you are.  Let me know if you find out!

Comment: @Brian I'm expecting to find out once I've beaten the last level and the mystery house marathon but...jeez, they're hard!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was digging around the internet this morning and found [this](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii-u/718915-super-mario-3d-world/cheats).  It looks like to get all the stickers, you need to do this:

- FINAL CHARACTER STAMPS - Beating every level with every character will get you their final Character Stamp. This includes World 12 (Crown).

Looks like we have our work cut out for us, Ben!

Comment: Oh good lord I quit

Comment: I am going to see how far I can make it...

Comment: @BenBrocka - I only have 33 more stars, 4 stamps and 10 goal flags to collect!